# Git "the followring untracked files would be overwritten by merge" after trying to pull with --allow-unrelated-histories

Tags: git

So, a client came to me with his project already developed and maintained by another company.
I cloned it, created my git repo, pushed etc.
Now I am trying to pull on the ssh, but their repo is still connected.
I changed it with `git remote set-url origin {my-repo-url}`.
I tried `git pull origin master` then and that's when the first error occured:

> * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
>    * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
>    fatal: refusing to merge unrelated
>    histories

Then I tried `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

The next error occured:

> The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by
>   merge:

and a list files.

I tried commiting those files, without pushing and then pulling again, but the same error showed.

What is the correct way of switching the remote and taking over the work of this project ?

EDIT: I would like to keep those files, because they seem to be some images of the products uploaded on the production website and I do not have them locally.

Comment: If by "those files" in "I like to keep those files" you mean the ones listed as "would be overwritten", then that is in contradiction to "I do not have them locally". The worktree *is* local and you *do* have them. Just move them out of the way, no?

Comment: @j6t these files are on the production server, I do not have them locally on my PC. I don't want to delete them after the pull.